# How do I generate a XSLT stylesheet for the following TEI snipet?

Tags: xslt, tei

i wanted to ask you for help. I am totally new to XSLT and i wanted to know if someone can show me the right XSLT stylesheet for the following TEI-snipet:

```
<div>
    <head>Weitere Aufzählungen</head>
    <list rend="numbered">
        <item n="1">A</item>
        <item n="2">B</item>                           
        <item n="3">C<list rend="numbered">
            <item n="3.1">a</item>
            <item n="3.2">b</item>
            </list>
        </item>
    </list>
</div>
```

The Output should look like that in the HTML-Document:

```
1. A
2. B
3. C
    3.1 a
    3.2 b
```

Thank you so much for helping me :)

Comment: Well, which HTML markup do you want to generate exactly? The exact look is not something XSLT creates. And have you tried to start reading an XSLT book like https://cranesoftwrights.github.io/books/ptux/index.htm or an online tutorial?

Comment: Thanks for answer,

Comment: yes I tried it already, but it could not help me

Comment: Do those `item/@n` attributes always start with the index `1`, as in the example (e.g. `1,2,3`, `3.1,3.2`)? Or can there be lists where you want the numbering to be started with a different number?

Comment: No, ist should be outlayed as above, but instead of 1,2,3, it can be also I,II,III and than, you know III.1, III.2 and so on. That does not matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a text output, the following stylesheet with `<xsl:output method="text" />` will do. It distinguishes the level of indentation by counting the item ancestor nodes and adds an extra `.` on level 0.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:variable name="newLine"  select="'&#xa;'" />

    <xsl:template match="text()" />

    <xsl:template match="/div/list">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="item" />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::item"><xsl:text>   </xsl:text></xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:value-of select="@n" />
        <xsl:if test="not(ancestor::item)"><xsl:text>.</xsl:text></xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(' ',text(),$newLine)" />
        <xsl:apply-templates select="list" />
    </xsl:template>   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output is:**

```
1. A
2. B
3. C
   3.1 a
   3.2 b
```

BTW you may need to add an appropriate namespace declaration for the TEI namespace to the `xsl:stylesheet` element.

Comment: It didn't work out. I just added your code into the XSLT Sheet, but it did not appear in the HTML-Document

Comment: If I use the <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes" /> tag, the whole document appears in plain text. But I want to have the output styled as it is in the normal document. Do you know what I can change here? Maybe I could send you the documents?

Comment: You could set the output `method="html"`. But the result will still be text and no HTML `list` like `<ul>` or `<ol>` or something like that. If you want an HTML result in an HTML document, I really need more information.

Comment: Hey, sorry for very late reply, it worked out for me, thank you somuch for your help ;)

Comment: Thanks for your appropriate reply and welcome to StackOverflow.